# "Good" method to call method on each object using Stream API

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Is it possible to run a method, in a consumer, like a method reference, but on the object passed to the consumer:

```
Arrays.stream(log.getHandlers()).forEach(h -> h.close());
```

would be a thing like:

```
Arrays.stream(log.getHandlers()).forEach(this::close);
```

but that's not working...

Is there a possibility with method references, or is `x -> x.method()` the only way working here?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You don't need `this`. `YourClassName::close` will call the `close` method on the object passed to the consumer :

```
Arrays.stream(log.getHandlers()).forEach(YourClassName::close);
```

There are four kinds of method references ([Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)):

```
Kind                                                                         Example
----                                                                         -------
Reference to a static method                                                 ContainingClass::staticMethodName
Reference to an instance method of a particular object                       containingObject::instanceMethodName
Reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type  ContainingType::methodName
Reference to a constructor                                                   ClassName::new
```

In your case, you need the third kind.

Comment: Thank you! Missed that "third kind" ;)

Comment: @Jofkos: as far as I can see in my “real-life code” that third kind is the most important kind. There are just so many already existing methods having the right signature for either `map`, `filter` or `forEach`…

Answer (score 13):

I suppose it should be:

```
Arrays.stream(log.getHandlers()).forEach(Handler::close);
```

Provided the `log.getHandlers()` returns an array of objects of type `Handler`.

Answer (score 8):

Sure, but you must use the correct syntax of [method reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html), i.e. pass the class to which the `close()` method belong:

```
Arrays.stream(log.getHandlers()).forEach(Handler::close);
```